# IF in VBS is not validate

Tags: vbscript

I am a beginner on VBScript files IF I try to validate the version of OS if is Microsoft Windows XP Professional or Microsoft Windows 7 Professional I need help how can I fix this following code:

```
set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")
Dim os_7, os_xp
os_7="Microsoft Windows 7 Professional"
os_xp="Microsoft Windows XP Professional"
for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")
    If Process.Name = "notes2.exe"  then
        WScript.Echo "Please Close the Lotus Notes Application and try again"
        WScript.quit
    End If
exit for

next
Set SystemSet = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf ("Win32_OperatingSystem") 

for each System in SystemSet 

 WScript.Echo System.Caption 
    If System.Caption = os_7 Then

        WScript.Echo "in  7"
    Else If System.Caption = os_xp Then

            WScript.Echo "in XP"
            WScript.quit
        Else 
            WScript.Echo "Is not supported "
        End If
    End If
Exit for
next
}
```

appreciate very much your help

Comment: What is the problem with the code? Please provide the error/warning?

Comment: Above code is working for me

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you delete the "}" in the last line of your code snippet?

Comment: Hoo this part is only when I put the code on this page sorry the organically code is not have this character "{}"

Answer (score 0):

This code classic for the good-old SELECT CASE

```
set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")
Dim os_7, os_xp
os_7="Microsoft Windows 7 Professional"
os_xp="Microsoft Windows XP Professional"
for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")
    If Process.Name = "notes2.exe"  then
        WScript.Echo "Please Close the Lotus Notes Application and try again"
        WScript.quit
    End If
exit for

next
Set SystemSet = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf ("Win32_OperatingSystem") 

for each System in SystemSet 

 WScript.Echo System.Caption
Select Case System.Caption
Case os_7

        WScript.Echo "in  7"
Case os_xp

            WScript.Echo "in XP"
            WScript.quit
Case Else 
            WScript.Echo "Is not supported "
End Select
Exit for
next
```

Comment: Is not working I running I have the same problem is get my the message "Is not Supported"

Answer (score 0):

I replaced your select case section with the following and got it to work.

```
set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")

for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")
    If Process.Name = "notes2.exe"  then
        WScript.Echo "Please Close the Lotus Notes Application and try again"
        WScript.quit
    End If
exit for

next
Set SystemSet = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf ("Win32_OperatingSystem") 

for each System in SystemSet 
    WScript.Echo System.caption
    If (instr(System.Caption, "Windows 7")) Then
        wscript.echo "Windows 7 found"
    ElseIF (instr(System.Caption, "Windows XP")) Then
        Wscript.echo "Windows xp found."
    Else
        Wscript.echo "Unsuported Operating system."
    End If
Exit for
next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strVer = wshShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\CurrentVersion")   
arrVer = Split(strVer, ".")

if arrVer(0) = 5 then "XP"
      if arrVer(0) = 6 AND arrVer(1) = 0  then "Vista"
      if arrVer(0) = 6 AND arrVer(1) = 1 then "Win7"
      if arrVer(0) = 6 AND arrVer(1) = 2 then "Win8"
      if arrVer(0) = 6 AND arrVer(1) = 3 then "Win Blue"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
  '----------------------------------------------------
  ' CODE BY: zhangbo2012
  ' Email  : zhangbo2012@outlook.com
  ' FROM   : China
  '----------------------------------------------------
  ' WMI:Win32_OperatingSystem
  '----------------------------------------------------
   On error resume next
   Set WMI_Obj = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem", , 48)
   For each obj in WMI_Obj
        wscript.echo " Caption = " & obj.Caption
   Next
```